# How can I pass in props from App.js to my login component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, passport.js

I'm new to React. I'm having trouble with getting React to recognize a prop passed in from App.js to the Login component. Specifically what I'm trying to do is getting React to do two things: 1. To check if a user is logged in. 2. What user is currently logged in. I'm using Passport, passport-local, Mongoose, MongoDB, Axios, Express, and react-router-dom to make this happen. When I attempt to log in a user I created in the database I get the following in the console:

```
TypeError: "this.props.updateUser is not a function"
    onSubmit login.component.js:42
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from "axios";

/* Begin Import Components */
import NavigationBar from "./components/navbar.component";

import MainLanding from "./components/main-landing.component";
import Contact from "./components/general-components/contact.component";
import Register from "./components/general-components/register.component";
import Login from "./components/general-components/login.component";
import ProductsList from "./components/product-components/products-list.component";
import ProductDetails from "./components/product-components/product-details.component";
import ProductCreate from "./components/product-components/product-create.component";
import ProductEdit from "./components/product-components/product-edit.component";
import ProductDelete from "./components/product-components/product-delete.component";
import UsersList from "./components/user-components/users-list.component";
import UserDetails from "./components/user-components/user-details.component";
import OrdersList from "./components/order-components/orders-list.component";
import OrderDetails from "./components/order-components/order-details.component";
import OrderCreate from "./components/order-components/order-create.component";
import OrderEdit from "./components/order-components/order-edit.component";
/* End Import Components */

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        loggedIn: false,
        user: {}
    }

    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.updateUser = this.updateUser.bind(this)
  }

  getUser() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/logged_in').then(response => {
      console.log('Get user response: ')
      console.log(response.data)
      if (response.data.user) {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          user: response.data.user
        })
      } else {
        console.log('Get user: no user');
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          user: {}
        })
      }
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  updateUser(userObject) {
    this.setState(userObject)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar />
        <div className="container">
          {/* Begin Routes. Begin General Routes */}
          <Route path="/" exact component={MainLanding} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}/>
          {/* End General Routes. Begin Products Routes */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/products/" exact component={ProductsList} />
            <Route path="/products/new" exact component={ProductCreate} />
            <Route path="/products/:id" exact component={ProductDetails} />
            <Route path="/products/:id/edit" exact component={ProductEdit} />
            <Route path="/products/:id/delete" exact component={ProductDelete} />
          </Switch>
          {/* End Products Routes. Begin Users Routes */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/users/" exact component={UsersList} />
            <Route path="/users/:id" exact component={UserDetails} />
          </Switch>
          {/* End Users Routes. Begin Orders Routes */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/orders/" exact component={OrdersList} />
            <Route path="/orders/new" exact component={OrderCreate} />
            <Route path="/orders/:id" exact component={OrderDetails} />
            <Route path="/orders/:id/edit" exact component={OrderEdit} />
          </Switch>
          {/* End Orders Routes. End Routes */}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Login Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }

        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onchangePassword = this.onchangePassword.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeUsername(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onchangePassword(e) {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/login", {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }).then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.props.updateUser({
                        loggedIn: true,
                        username: res.data.username
                    })
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        this.setState({
            username: "",
            password: ""
        })
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="text-center">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor="formUsername">Username</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                        controlid="formUsername"
                                        type="text"
                                        value={this.state.username}
                                        onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                                        placeholder="Enter username"
                                        />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor="formPassword">Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                        controlid="formPassword"
                                        type="password"
                                        value={this.state.password}
                                        onChange={this.onchangePassword}
                                        placeholder="Enter password"
                                        />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Button variant="success" type="submit">
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `updateUser()` is defined correctly but you need to pass it to the **Login** component:

### App.js

```js
<Route path='/login' render={(props) =>
  <Login {...props} updateUser={this.updateUser} />
}/>
```

This will append `props.updateUser` to the **Login** component on top of all the props from the parent component (App.js).

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to be that you still not put updateUser as props of Login component. You could try like this

```
<Route path='/login' render={(props) =>
  <Login {...props} updateUser={this.updateUser} />
}/>
```

But, i think that this.props.updateUser() may also be come from redux of application (mapDispatchtoProps). If so, you just connect Login component to redux, don't need to put this function as props in Login component.